# React native Azure devops Build# Expo pipeline failing

Tags: android, react-native, expo, azure-pipelines, iphone-developer-program

I have my react native app.
I m using azure devops pipe line #

and using azure build agent#  vmImage: 'macOS-latest'

https://medium.com/@raghu1286/react-native-expo-android-ios-ci-builds-for-azure-devops-5458eb0b5e4a

I followed all steps with  above link

**turtle setup:ios
EXPO_IOS_DIST_P12_PASSWORD=$(EXPO_IOS_DIST_P12_PASSWORD) turtle build:ios -u $(EXPO_CLI_USER) -p $(EXPO_CLI_PASSWORD) --team-id $(Apple-Team-Id) --dist-p12-path <p12_path> --provisioning-profile-path <provision_path> --release-channel deployment**

when this command start executing it gives me below error #

[15792] ERROR: Error: Request failed with status code 404
at createError (/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/node/18.15.0/x64/lib/node_modules/tu.......

****ls: *.ipa: No such file or directory
File name to publish IOS****